# android studio | setting specific color to transparent on image

Tags: android, image, android-layout

My goal is to make particular color transparent on image as in tiles to games where one plain background color is ignored while loadling.

What I've read

1. [Draw a Bitmap on a Canvas replacing Black Pixels to Transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14895015/draw-a-bitmap-on-a-canvas-replacing-black-pixels-to-transparent)
2. [Replacing a color in a Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18748694/replacing-a-color-in-a-bitmap)
3. [How to change colors of a Drawable in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309629/how-to-change-colors-of-a-drawable-in-android)
4. [Android: Make specific (green) color in background image transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155999/android-make-specific-green-color-in-background-image-transparent)
5. [Android how to apply mask on ImageView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14801075/android-how-to-apply-mask-on-imageview?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Code I have added to default .java

```
ImageView log = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iconLogo);
int col = ResourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(), R.color.colorTrans, null);
log.getDrawable().mutate().setColorFilter(col, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
//log.getDrawable().setColorFilter(col, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN); //take2
//log.setColorFilter(R.color.colorTrans, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN); //take3
```

Making image mutable provides better result but still does not subtract `R.color.colorTrans` from image. Overall after playing around with filter it seems to be working as a filter above whole image and there is no search for the color I set hence that color always present and not excluded not depending on mode used.

Second option

```
 public static Bitmap getBitmapWithTransparentBG(Bitmap srcBitmap, int BgColor) {
        Bitmap result = srcBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
        int nWidth = result.getWidth();
        int nHeight = result.getHeight();
        for (int y = 0; y < nHeight; ++y)
            for (int x = 0; x < nWidth; ++x) {
                int nPixelColor = result.getPixel(x, y);
                if (nPixelColor == BgColor)
                    result.setPixel(x, y, Color.TRANSPARENT);
            }
        return result;
    }
```

Using only one 600x600 px png file increases app loading time from 1-2s to 8-12s moreover it does not remove specific color. Hence can not be used for multiple igames.

What I need again is to remove/ignore specific color from Image in ImageView but not to make all pic transparent. Since games use tile maps without alpha then there must be a way to do it without adding alpha mask to them.

Comment: https://www.spriters-resource.com/resources/sheets/20/21264.png here is example of what I have meant. Orange color is ignored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution here [unable to transparent pixels of a bitmap image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31746813/8859693)
.

However using it even on one picture increases loading time drastically. Probably `.png` with already cleared background would be better to use.